# MAVEN svn error: Not working on version higher han svn 1.6

Tags: maven, svn

I am using buildnumber-maven-plugin and when ever i am using higher SVN version than 1.6 i am getting below error.

> [Step 1/1] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.0:create (svn-revision)
>   on project SAP: Cannot get the revision information from the scm
>   repository :
>
> [16:17:16][Step 1/1] [ERROR] Exception while executing SCM command.
>   svn: The path 'D:\BuildAgent\work\2570b16cd297262f' appears to be part
>   of a Subversion 1.7 or greater

Is there any dependency between maven plugins and svn version?

> [16:17:16][Step 1/1] [ERROR] working copy.  Please upgrade your
>   Subversion client to use this
>
> [16:17:16][Step 1/1] [ERROR] working copy.

Comment: Very obviously there is. And especially there's a dependency on the svn version as the repository format changed between svn 1.6 and 1.7.

Comment: Use an more uptodate version of the [buildnumber-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/)